# 4 spheres in cylinder

Tags: geometry

I am new to this website, so I apologize if I am doing something wrong.

In the diagram, there are $4$ spheres in a cyclinder.
The only information given is this:
The radius of each sphere is $5.3$ cm (diameter is $10.6$ cm)
And the height of the cylinder $10.6$ cm

How do I find the total surface area of the cylinder?

[image]

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmYkZ.png)

Edit: to those who have provided a solution, thank you. I will be deleting this soon.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean by the 'width of the cylinder,' I interpreted that to mean the diameter of the circular cross-section, is that correct?

Comment: The 'width' refers to the rectangular shape (that wraps around the circular face)

Comment: I only have the diagram to go by.

Comment: "I will be deleting this soon." If you are going to post a question and then delete it after you get answers don't bother posting in the first place! That is really disrespectful to those that took time answering you and is not acceptable practice here.

Comment: I think they meant deleting their account.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect centres of the four spheres you obtain a square, whose diagonal, plus two radius at each end, is the diametre of the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

If the spheres centers are forming a square, the side of the square will be $2r$.

Referring a coordinate system by putting the square vertex at $(\pm r,\pm r)$, then the cylinder will contact each sphere at angles $45°$, $135°$, $225°$ and $315°$.

So the contact will happen at distance $R=r\sqrt{2}+r$ from the center of the square, which is the radius of the big cylinder. First term is the half size of the square diagonal, and the second term is the radius again.

Then, the area of the cylinder will be $A=hr(\sqrt{2}+1)=10.6 \cdot 5.3(\sqrt{2}+1)=135.6cm^2$

Comment: Guess it should be $\sqrt{2}r+r$ instead.

Comment: corrected......